# Problema con If y TextBox - C#

Tags: c#

Mi `if` no evalúa correctamente, quiero que verifique que los `textbox` no estén vacíos o que `textbox1` o `textbox2` no sea `"var"`, de lo contrario marque error.

```
if (textbox1 != "" || textbox1 != "var" && textbox2 != "" || textbox2 != "var" && comboBox1 !=""){        
    MessageBox.Show("Mandar datos");

    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta carece de la informacion necesaria para que alguno de nosotros pueda ayudarte. Por favor consulta la [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorarla.

Comment: a que te referis con no valida? que es lo que tiene que hacer? que datos recibe? sigue estando incompleta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el problema esta en el  [orden de precedencia de los operadores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

&& se evalúa primero y luego se evalua ||

si tienes:

```
if (v1 != "" || v1 != "var" && v2 != "" || v2 != "var" && v3 !="")
```

se evalúa así:

```
if (v1 != "" || (v1 != "var" && v2 != "") || (v2 != "var" && v3 !=""))
```

y supongo que tu quieres que lo evalué así:

```
if ((v1 != "" || v1 != "var") && (v2 != "" || v2 != "var") && (v3 !=""))
```

si no estas seguro del orden de precedencia usa paréntesis para asegurarte.

Comment: este me sirvio, Gracias